# Excel: Writing a formula that uses Index/Match then checks a related cell for a value and researches for the next match if it finds an error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

[Here is a spreadsheet I quickly made up to try and explain the problem.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U9-O2dWqeApVj8zzPlapmBuSmKtayTERYOR9LgwBLE8/edit#gid=533275594)

I need to have a formula in the C column that goes to the second sheet and retrieves the data but if it yields an error in the D column I need it to go back and search for the next match until there is no longer an N/A value, or once it has searched the database it results in a message "Not used". In my actual project, I have 25,000 rows in three groups of columns so I unfortunately can't really do it by hand.

My current formula attempt:

```
=INDEX(Database!$A$2:$A$5, MATCH(B3, Database!$B$2:B$5, 0), IF(ISERROR(D3), INDEX('Database'!$A$2:$A$5, MATCH(B3, 'Component Database'!B$2:$B$5, 0)+2), " ")
```

I've tried a few other `IF/IFERROR/IFISERROR` but they have all resulted in either endless loops or just a random value that was ahead a certain number of rows when using the "+1, +2, etc." after the match function.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up getting it to work two levels deeper with this format.

```
=IF(
  AND(
    INDEX(*Table with value you want returned*, 
    MATCH(*Specific Cell*, *Table to search for cell*, 0)), 

  ISERROR(
    INDEX(*Table of hidden helper column with first result when value is searched*, 
    MATCH(*Cell to see if there is an error*, *Table with return value*, 0)))), 
        IFERROR(
            INDEX(*Table with value you want returned*,
            SMALL(
                IF(*Column*=*Value to be matched in column*,
                    ROW(*Column with matched value*)-ROW(*First Cell of Column with matching value*)+1,
                    ROW(*Last cell in Match Column*)+1),*which match you want returned (1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc... (in 1, 2, 3, etc. format))*),1),  

  INDEX(*Table with value you want returned*, 
  MATCH(*Specific Cell*, *Table to search for cell*, 0))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `IFERROR` you can "nest" several formulas so that they are run in succession until one succeeds, e.g.

`=IFERROR(INDEX/MATCH1,IFERROR(INDEX/MATCH2,IFERROR(INDEX/MATCH3,"No matches)))`

Replace `INDEX/MATCH 1, 2 and 3` with actual formulas (don't include the `=`)

That will get you the result from the first formula.....unless it's an error in which case you get the result from the second....unless that's an error, in which case you get the result from Formula 3....unless that's an error in which case you get "No matches". You can keep on nesting many times (up to 64 is the limit)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately what I need though is for it to check a cell resulting from the index match for an error. So once I put this into the C column I need it to check the D coulmn for the error and if there is one to go back and search again in the C coulmn.